# How to install specific R version in ubuntu

Tags: 20.04, lubuntu, r

Good afternoon !

Under ubuntu , i'm trying to install a specific R version . so i downloaded the following .tar file :

https://cran.r-project.org/src/base/R-3/R-3.5.0.tar.gz

After that , i had unzipped the source. Then i had used :

```
cd /home/mouad//Téléchargements/R-3.5.0/
```

Then :

```
$ ./configure
```

Until this step , things were going properly. However , when trying to use `$make` the following error arises :

```
$ make
make: *** Pas de cible spécifiée et aucun makefile n'a été trouvé. Arrêt.
```

[image]

I'm a beginer in ubuntu.

Thank you for help !

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version? Why do you need fixed version of R?

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS 64 bits

Comment: Will 3.6.3 be good for you? It is packaged in [official repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/r-base-dev). So its installation is simple, fast and stable.

Comment: No , i need to use some older R packages

Comment: The pb is with the make command , i don't know how to create a makefile for the make command

Comment: Any suggestion !

Comment: You can always install previous version of specific package using guides like [this](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/219949047-Installing-older-versions-of-packages) - as simple as `require(devtools); install_version("ggplot2", version = "0.9.1", repos = "http://cran.r-project.org")`. Will it be good for you?

Comment: Currently , i have R 4 version installed. Some older packages will not work unless i use the older R 3.5 version

Comment: I just need to know why make isn't working that's all

Comment: If `make` says *"*** Pas de cible spécifiée et aucun makefile n'a été trouvé. Arrêt."* then it's unlikely that `./configure` went "properly" - please check its output for errors

Comment: @steeldriver , yes it gives no in some lines

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Binary packages approach**

Before proceeding I need to repeat my points - you can install R 3.6.3 using packages from [official repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/r-base-dev). Or install R 4.0 [from CRAN](https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/). And then install here R-package with [specified version](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/219949047-Installing-older-versions-of-packages) using commands like shown below:

```
require(devtools); 
install_version("ggplot2", version = "0.9.1", repos = "http://cran.r-project.org")
```

Note: for package names and versions consult with [R package index](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/index.html).

**Manual compilation approach**

If you really want to compile older version of R by yourself, then read the next text carefully. Be ready for 900 Mb download and 2200 Mb disk space usage (numbers are shown for fresh system).

To compile older version of R you need to enable source code repositories (*deb-src*) in Software & Updates (`software-properties-gtk`), then download the source code, compile it and install compiled binaries and other components. Use commands below:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get build-dep r-base-dev

cd ~/Downloads
wget -c https://cran.r-project.org/src/base/R-3/R-3.5.0.tar.gz
tar -xf R-3.5.0.tar.gz
cd R-3.5.0
./configure
make -j9
sudo make install
```

Then you can run this locally installed R version using its full path `/usr/local/bin/R`. It will allow you to have R 3.5 co-installed along with R 4.0 simultaneously.

Comment: I think the source R-3.5.0.tar.gz itself doesn't have a makefile or I need to use sudo ./configure´. I will just try to install the wanted packages manually from R studio

Comment: Thank you a lot for your precious help !

Comment: For quick reference, this is the command to install R 3.6.3 binary:

`sudo apt-get install r-base-dev=3.6.3-2`